# 'pinging' if site busts out of frames

Tags: javascript, iframe, onbeforeunload

I was wondering if there is any method of checking if a site will bust out of an iframe before my app puts it in an iframe.

Alternatively maybe someone knows of a database api that has this info.

Currently I'm using a beforeunload event to prevent a site from taking over the page the user is currently on.

Comment: It _must_ be possible for software to predict future events, otherwise how does the Magic 8-ball app on my Android phone work?

Comment: What I'm looking at doing is coordinating with the background page of my extension, and watching to see if the site had broken out of the page, by keeping track of the tab's id in chrome.